# Custom ArrayList not showing proper output

Tags: android

I have arraylist that holds xml data.The xml data is loaded correctly but it not showing correct o/p on listview.The o/p is like com.example.questions.QuestionArrayList@b4dd8e30
My code is

```
public class Test extends Activity 
{
    private TextView question;
    private RadioButton rdooption1;
    private RadioButton rdooption2;
    private RadioButton rdooption3;
    private RadioButton rdooption4;
    private static final String FILENAME = "xmlFileName.xml";
    private FileInputStream fin;

    QuestionArrayList currentquestion = null;
    List<QuestionArrayList> questions = null;
    private ListView details;   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question_layout);
        details=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    }
    private void parseXML(XmlPullParser xpp) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException 
    {
    questions= new ArrayList<QuestionArrayList>();
    currentquestion = new QuestionArrayList();
    while(xpp.next()!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT )
    {
    if (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
    {
    continue;
    }
    String name = xpp.getName();
    if(name.equals("Question"))
    {                               
    currentquestion.setQuestion_type(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "id"));
    currentquestion.setQuestion_type(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "type"));
    currentquestion.setQuestion_name(xpp.nextText());
    }
    if(currentquestion!=null)
    {
    questions.add(currentquestion);
    }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<QuestionArrayList> arrayadpater = new ArrayAdapter<QuestionArrayList>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,questions);
    details.setAdapter(arrayadpater);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayAdapter` will use the `toString` method of the `Object` passed in the constructor

From [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html):

```
A concrete BaseAdapter that is backed by an array of arbitrary objects. By default this     
class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView. If you want to  
use a more complex layout, use the constructors that also takes a field id. That field id 
should reference a TextView in the larger layout resource. 


However the TextView is referenced, it will be filled with the toString() of each 
object in the array. You can add lists or arrays of custom objects. Override the 
toString() method of your objects to determine what text will be displayed for the item 
in the list.
```

Look at the second paragraph, it says that if you are passing custom `Object` you should override the `toString` method in your custom `Object` class.

Comment: can you give me simple example

Comment: Look at [Overriding toString in Java](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

I got the simple ans of my own question 
we have to override tostring() method of java in class.I writing simple example here

```
public class QuestionArrayList 
{
public String question_name;
public String option_one;
public String getQuestion_name() 
    {
        return question_name;
    }
    public void setQuestion_name(String question_name) 
    {
        this.question_name = question_name;
    }
public String getOption_one() {
        return option_one;
    }
    public void setOption_one(String option_one) {
        this.option_one = option_one;
    }
@Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "question_name:"+ question_name+ "|option_one:"+ option_one;
    }
}
```

you can assign these object to the listview simply